# How to map Image type in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I have at my SQL Server 2000 Database a column with type **Image**. How can I map it into NHibernate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We used BinaryBlob on the mapping config file, and byte[] on the property.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code that i have used to map an image field. Where BlogImage was a column of Image Datatype mapped to byte type property BlogImage. length="2147483647" was used to ensure copy of full image in to database as nhibernate some times limit the max size of data that is going to be inserted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true">
<class name="EAS.MINDSPACE.Infrastructure.Business.Entities.BlogMaster,EAS.MINDSPACE.Infrastructure.Business.Entities" lazy="false" table="BlogMaster" schema="dbo" >
<id name="BlogId" column="BlogId">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
<property name="BlogData" column="BlogData" />
<property name="BlogImage" column="BlogImage" length="2147483647"  />
<property name="UserId" column="UserId" />
  <property name="CreatedByName" column="CreatedBy" />
  <property name="CreatedOn" column="CreatedOn" />
  <property name="ReplyCount" column="ReplyCount" />

 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate 3.x does all the magic it self.

Sql:

```
Create table tblCompany (..., Logo image);
```

NHibernate-Mapping (important to set length!!!):

```
<class name="Company"
     table="tblCompany">
     ...         
     <property name="_logo"
          column="Logo"
          not-null="false"
          length="2147483647"
          access="field" />
     ...
</class>
```

C#-Class:

```
public class Company {
    ...
    private Image _logo;
    ...
}
```